# If I split a 24 card deck evenly between three players, how do I find the probability that each player has at least one card from the hearts suit?

Tags: probability

For information on the deck, the four suits are split evenly, with 6 cards of each suit. Each player has 8 cards.

I've been struggling with this question for several hours now, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You will have more chances to get an answer if you show us results (even partial and inconclusive) of your struggles.

Comment: HINT: Count no. of ways player A have no hearts, then player B, etc.  Finally, deal with double counted cases.